# CompilationLock error in web forms page directive

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

My company has a web forms project that we converted to an MVC 3 project over a month ago. Everything works great except for this annoying error that the parser gives on web forms page directives. I'm not sure when this started. I only just started noticing it a week ago, but it could have been there since we transitioned the project.

We followed [this tutorial](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/05/convert-web-forms-mvc3-how-to.html) when modifying our web forms project to support MVC 3. The project compiles just fine. Beyond this annoying underline (shown below) there is no problem. Web forms and MVC have played nice together so far. However, intellisense within .ASPX markup does not work while the parser is displaying this error.

[Image](http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/compilationlockexception.jpg)

> The type initializer for 'System.Web.Compilation.CompilationLock' threw an exception.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue? I have scanned the web.config as well as unloaded the project and scanned the .csproj xml. I can't see anything wrong but I also don't really know what I'm looking for. Google doesn't turn up anything useful for this error in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what was causing this. But a complete re-install of .NET and Visual Studio fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with my ASP.NET Web Site not building and producing the same useless error.

For me, the solution was fixing the capitalization of the sessionState mode in my Web.config:

```xml
<sessionState mode="Off"/>
```

(It may be 9 years too late, but I wanted this answer to be documented *literally anywhere on the internet*.)

Comment: Mine was similar.  It turned out I had misfired a Ctrl + S, and there was an errant 's' in Web.config outside of any xml tags.  Visual Studio only underlined it with a green squiggly, so it wasn't overly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Hanselmans's write up and compare your references and web.config:

[Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)

Comment: The project is already successfully upgraded to MVC 3 and it works fine. I just have this weird parser error. The project compiles and runs. That blog did not help me discover what could be causing this error under ASPX page directives.